# Google Api ClientのonConnectedが呼ばれない

Tags: android, java, google-maps

Google Map Apiを使ったアプリを作成しようとしています。

そこで下記コードでGoogleApiClientの初期化を試みましたがonConnectedが呼ばれません。

コード

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private SampleApplication mApplication;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    @State Location mCurrentLocation;
    @State boolean mRequestingLocationUpdate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**
         * サインイン済みかどうかをチェックする
         * サインインしていない場合、SigninActivityを立ち上げサインインさせる
         */
        /*
        if (!readUserInfo()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SigninActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        */

        /**
         * ログインチェック終わり
         */


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Use ButterKnife
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        // Use icepick
        Icepick.restoreInstanceState(this, savedInstanceState);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        mApplication = (SampleApplication) getApplication();
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(mGoogleApiClient != null&&mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()&&!mRequestingLocationUpdate){
            startLocationUpdate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Icepick.saveInstanceState(this, outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d("==debug==", "Initialized Google map");
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        //googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Title"));
        createLocationRequest();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d("==debug==", "Connected to Google API");
        if(mRequestingLocationUpdate){
            startLocationUpdate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d("==debug==", "Connected suspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d("==debug==", "Connection failed" + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(
                        mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(),
                        mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()), 15);
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
    }

    private boolean readUserInfo(){
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String consumerKey = prefs.getString("consumerKey", null);
        if(consumerKey == null)
            return false;
        Long userId = prefs.getLong("userId", 0);
        if(userId == 0)
            return false;
        String accessToken = prefs.getString("accessToken", null);
        if(accessToken == null)
            return false;

        //ConsumerKeyとUserIdを設定ファイルに保存
        mApplication.consumerKey=consumerKey;
        mApplication.userId=userId;
        mApplication.accessToken=accessToken;
        return true;
    }

    private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
        Log.d("==debug==", "Building Google API client");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    private void createLocationRequest(){
        Log.d("==debug==", "Creating location request");
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(800);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    private void startLocationUpdate(){
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    private void stopLocationUpdate(){
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }


}
```

このコードの中に複数デバッグのログを出すようにしていますが、onConnected,onConnectionSuspended,onConnectionFailedが呼ばれません。他のデバッグ文は呼ばれています。
logcatにもエラーのようなものは見られませんでした。
どこが間違っているかわかりません。どなたかアドバイスをいただけないでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `buildGoogleApiClient()` メソッドで `mGoogleApiClient.connect();` を実行する必要があるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。できました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buildGoogleApiClient()` メソッドで `mGoogleApiClient.connect();` を実行する必要があるのではないでしょうか。

---

*この投稿は [@user9156 さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/18289/google-api-client%e3%81%aeonconnected%e3%81%8c%e5%91%bc%e3%81%b0%e3%82%8c%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment16927_18289) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*